# Waiting to volley response to arrive before returning it's response

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, android-volley

I built a login system that checks the input of the user and checks with the data if he can log in.

The server side of the application is working fine but I'm not able to stop the main thread of the application and wait for the response to arrive.

basically I'm using Volley library to communicate with my server. first of all, is send the username to check if such one even exists in the database, secondly, I check the combination of the password and username. and if these checks are fine I receive the user unique id which the user needs for the rest of the app.

This is the code that handles the java login process:

```
    public void toMainLobby(View view)
    {
        if(LoginIsValid()) //check if the user can log in
        {
            getUserID();
        }
    }

    /**
     * the function checks if the login details are correct
     * @return boolean whether the login details are correct
     */
    private boolean LoginIsValid()
    {
        pop_up_message.setText("");

        //check if the fields are empty
        if(username.getText().toString().equals("") || password.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            pop_up_message.setText("Please fill all fields");
            return false;
        }

        resetBooleans();

        Log.d("FinalDebug","send the request");

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                checkIfUsernameIsTaken(new VolleyCallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d("FinalDebug","on success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        waitForResponse();

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(!flag)
        {
            pop_up_message.setText("Username doesn't exist");
            return false;
        }

        resetBooleans();

        checkLogin(new VolleyCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                hasChanged = true;
            }
        });

        waitForResponse();

        if(!flag)
        {
            pop_up_message.setText("Password incorrect");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void getUserID()
    {
        StringRequest getuserid = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    if(jsonObject.has("ID"))
                    {
                        String value = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                        String newvalue = value.substring(2,value.length() - 2);
                        if(!newvalue.equals("0"))
                        {
                            id =  Integer.parseInt(newvalue);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),newvalue,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),iJam_Main_Lobby.class);
                            intent.putExtra("username",username.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("id", id);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("type_of_request","GET_USER_ID");
                hashMap.put("username",username.getText().toString());
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        MySingelton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(getuserid);
    }

    //private methods
    private void checkLogin(final VolleyCallBack volleyCallBack)
    {
        StringRequest checkLog = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    if(jsonObject.has("isValid"))
                    {

                        String ans = jsonObject.getString("isValid"); //extracts the isValid value
                        //checks the response
                        String newString = ans.substring(1,ans.length() - 1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"login response: " + newString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("result from server",newString);

                        if(!newString.equals("true"))
                        {
                            flag = false;

                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                volleyCallBack.onSuccess();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("type_of_request","LOGIN");
                hashMap.put("username",username.getText().toString());
                hashMap.put("password",password.getText().toString());
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        MySingelton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(checkLog);
    }

    private void resetBooleans()
    {
        flag = false;
        hasChanged = false;
    }

    private void checkIfUsernameIsTaken(final VolleyCallBack volleyCallBack)
    {
        StringRequest checkUsername = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    if(jsonObject.has("isValid"))
                    {

                        String ans = jsonObject.getString("isValid"); //extracts the isValid value
                        //checks the response
                        String newString = ans.substring(1,ans.length() - 1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Response about username existence: " + newString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("result from server",newString);
                        if(newString.equals("true"))
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                hasChanged = true;
                volleyCallBack.onSuccess();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("type_of_request","CHECK_USERNAME_EXISTENCE");
                hashMap.put("username",username.getText().toString());
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        MySingelton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(checkUsername);
    }

    private void waitForResponse()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (!hasChanged)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

*disclaimer - the toasts and the log.d lines are for debugging purposes.

Comment: In Android, we never stop the main Thread. we get a response in callback methods. Please go through basic Android tutorials as it will help in getting better understanding of the platform.

Comment: may be you can login check at server side by single request. you just check first username if correct then check again for password [at server-side] and then just both correct then return true otherwise false from server side.